# Find the critical point of a 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this function:

$f(x,y)=4x^3+2xy^2-x^2+4y^2$

The partial derivative of x and y are:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=12x^2+2y^2-2x$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=4xy+8y$

They ask me to find the critical points of that function but i can't figure it out.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The critical points are the $(x,y)$ coordinates where the partial derivatives are equal to $0$, so set $\partial f/\partial x= 0$ and $\partial f/\partial y = 0$ and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I know but i can't figure out how. I always get stuck and can't manage to find a value for x or y. All i managed to do is find y(4x+8)=0 so either y=0 or x = -2, but i don't know what to do from there.

Comment: i got this for the other partial derivative, x(6x-1)+y=0, so if x=o and y=0, or x=1/6 and y=0, does that mean the critical points are: (0,0), (1/6,0), (-2,0)?

Comment: So, as you said, when $\partial f/\partial y = 0$, that means $y(4x + 8) = 0$, so either $y = 0$ or $x = -2$.  But if $y = 0$, then from $\partial f/\partial x= 0$, we get that $x(12x - 2) = 0$, so either $x = 0$ or $x = \frac{1}{6}$.  This gives us the points $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{6}, 0)$.  If on the other hand $x = -2$, then from $\partial f/\partial x = 0$, we get $12(-2)^{2} + 2y^{2} - 2(-2) = 12(4) + 2y^{2} + 4 = 0$, and there are no real solutions for $y$ in this equation.  So, the critical points are only $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{6}, 0)$.  Where did you get $(-2,0)$ from?

Comment: y(4(-2)+8)=0 would also give us 0?

Comment: Yes but that's because we have $y \cdot 0$, which of course equals $0$.  When you get that $x = -2$ in the equation $y(4x + 8) = 0$, you then solve for $y$ in the *other* equation, not in the same equation you got the $x$ from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30043/discussion-between-spexel-and-user46944).